# How to disallow specific characters in Text Field (AlpacaJS)

Tags: alpacajs

How do I disallow specific characters in a text field? Using the `disallow` schema property seems to only check agains the **entire** string, as opposed to individual characters in the string.

Specifically looking to not allow `.` (decimals) in a text field but allow alphanumeric characters so:
`abc123` is okay but `abc.123` is not okay.

[Text Field Example 14 on the AlpacaJS website](http://www.alpacajs.org/docs/fields/text.html#toc_11) is an example. You can't input `Mickey` but you can do `abc Mickey`.

In my case I tried `"disallow": ["."]` which only stopped me from inputting `.` but not `.abc` or `123.456`.

I also tried to use the `pattern` field, which I can't find any documentation on, but that seems designed to limit to an actual pattern (i.e. `"pattern": "/^[a-z0-9]+$/i"` didn't work).

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like I might be able to accomplish this using custom validation but unfortunately the way we utilize AlpacaJS does not allow us to define code in the Options hash. For people who can use code in their Options hash here's the info- http://www.alpacajs.org/docs/api/validation.html

Comment: Do you want to block the user from entering the disallowed keys or you want to validate the field against those disallowed keys?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The goal is to validate any part of the field against any of the disallowed keys (i.e. validation failed based on a partial match). I did a little dive into the code itself this morning and I don't think this is possible based on how the disallow array is tested against the field's value. So, for anyone looking for similar behavior, I ended up making a callback that removes all `.`s and we left the helper. It's not exactly what we initially intended but it's close enough. More info here- http://www.alpacajs.org/docs/api/events.html#toc_2